# What happens to the environment when you run "su -c"?

Tags: bash, unix, sh, su

What happens to the environment when you run "su -c"?

The reason I ask, is this mysterious behavior:

```
bash$ which firefox
/usr/local/bin/firefox
bash$ su - user -c "echo $PATH"
bin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin:/opt/java/bin:/usr/local/bin:... 
bash$ su - user -c "firefox ..."
-bash: firefox: command not found
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I assume firefox is in the $PATH echoed by the first command?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are seeing is the fact that `$PATH` is expanded in the first users shell during argument processing, before the `su(1)` command runs, so it looks like it always does. If you use hard quotes (`'echo $PATH'`) you should see something different, or just do `\$`.

This will preserve the `$PATH` syntax until after the `su(1)` command runs. While it normally doesn't fiddle with the environment, it does start a new shell, and so you should check for `PATH=` lines in the various shell startup scripts.

Your `su(1)` has a `-c` option, so you would seem to be on Linux. On a Mac or a BSD you would get a simplified `PATH` instead of the login `PATH` but you would still have the same "when did I expand PATH?" issue.

Answer (score 7):

When `su -` or `su -l` is used, it emulates a login session, which involves resetting the environment to a clean state.

On Arch Linux, `su -` uses the hardcoded string `/usr/ucb:/bin:/usr/bin:/etc` as the new `$PATH`. On other systems, it might read `ENV_SUPATH` from `/etc/login.defs`, or rely on PAM to set up environment.

**`su ... "echo $PATH"` lies, because the `$PATH` part is expanded by your current shell, way before `su` is launched. Use `su ... 'echo $PATH'` instead (note the single quotes), or `su - -c env` (prints the complete environment).**